# IOS Core Data Inserts Fail

Tags: ios, core-data, insert

I have an issue that I suspect is related to NOT maintaining a proper reference to a Parent Entity Object.  It a basic 1 to many relationship, sqlite core data model.  EntityA is parent (one) and EntityB is child (many).  The relationship is properly configured in the data model

I create a EntityA object and automatically insert 5 default EntityB objects in the same process (context) and save the context and all works well.  1 master object is created along with the 5 child objects.

However in a later process, several views and perhaps days later, I need to navigate to a "Child Add" view (ultimately beginning from a selected row in a table view listing EntityA objects) ... When I've gathered the info necessary data for the child object, and I do a "Save" (context), it returns an error "Null" message.  I assume it is because core data (IOS) is not properly made aware of which EntityA object I'm dealing with at that time and won't insert objects into a many side entity blindly.

I'm wondering what I need to be passing from one view to the next to maintain a reference to the current "parent object" so that later child inserts can successfully occur?  (And how do I implement this passed reference when assigning data to the child object and execute "Save context")

Comment: Show some code and exception details

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the parent object, how are you inserting child objects in a relationship? You suspect it's doing so "blindly", but "blindly" how? The "many" side of what, if you don't have the parent?

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  How do I get (Keep) a reference to the parent entity as I navigate through the app views, and how to I use it on save of child objects when I arrive at the "child add" modal view?  I was viewing th parent object in a table, then move on to the parent detail view, then move on to the parent child existing objects view table, then I move on to a child object add view to add another object ...

Comment: After a little more doing, the context save is working now.  However I still have the same issue.  The child objects are saving, BUT WITHOUT a reference in the generated relationship attribute.  So they are essentially becoming instant orphans.

Comment: I learned one single line by studying the Apple Tagged Locations example that I could not find mentioned directly in probably 100 different web pages visited ... [self.event addTagsObject:tag];  ... for me ... [self.currentLoad addPayDetailsObject:self.currentPayItem];  I was passing in my current load object but I never knew how to refer to it when I was ready to save.  Good grief.